# About save the data named by the object of a var in R

Tags: r, object, var

I just want to use the object of a variable as the name of the object to save. For example:

```
y <- matrix(1:30,nrow=5)
name <- "CHLYT"
save(assign(name,y), file="J:/毕业设计/newdata/test.RData")
```

I want to save the variable "y" with the name "CHLYT", using the name stored in variable "name". I don't want to use `save(CHLYT,file="")`. And when I open the file "test.RData", I hope to see a variable "CHLYT" in my environment.

Comment: You want to use `"CHLYT"` as file name?

Comment: @Pgibas not the filename, but the name of var. When I open the file `test.RData`, I hope it will show a var named `CHLYT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an environment. (You could also just do it in the global environment, but I think this is cleaner.)

```
e <- new.env() # create new environment
assign(name, y, envir = e) # assign into that environment
save(list=name, envir = e, file="test.RData") # save from environment
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) # remove everything (for demonstration)
ls()
# character(0)
load("test.RData") # reload
ls()
# [1] "CHLYT"
CHLYT
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16   21   26
# [2,]    2    7   12   17   22   27
# [3,]    3    8   13   18   23   28
# [4,]    4    9   14   19   24   29
# [5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30
```

Note the use of the `list` and `envir` arguments to `save()`. `list` takes a vector of object names as character strings; this allows you to use your `name` variable inside `save`. The `envir` argument tells `save` where to look for the named objects...in this case, inside our new `e` environment.

When `load`ing, the `y` object now has the new object name and it is loaded into the .GlobalEnv by default.